# Expand And Group To Map For All Dates in Range

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that contains mapping and valid date ranges like so:

```
| foo_id | identifier_type | value | start_date | end_date   |  
|--------|-----------------|-------|------------|------------|
| 1      | colour          | red   | 1994-01-01 | 1997-04-01 |
| 1      | colour          | blue  | 1997-04-18 | 2100-12-31 |
| 2      | value           | 7     | 2000-01-01 | 2100-12-31 |
```

But I want to select the data so that I see ranges when there wasn't a valid mapping.

```
| foo_id | identifier_type | value | start_date | end_date   |
|--------|-----------------|-------|------------|------------|
| 1      | colour          | NULL  | 1990-01-01 | 1994-03-31 |
| 1      | colour          | red   | 1994-01-01 | 1997-04-01 |
| 1      | colour          | NULL  | 1997-04-02 | 1997-04-17 |
| 1      | colour          | blue  | 1997-04-18 | 2100-12-31 |
| 2      | value           | NULL  | 1990-01-01 | 1999-12-31 |
| 2      | value           | 7     | 2000-01-01 | 2100-12-31 |
```

I.e. for every id and identifer type in the table I want to see the rows representing any null mappings between any two dates in a range I can specify.

One way I could do this would be to select all the unique combinations, and all the dates in the range. Then do a left join on the mappings. And then finally group all the mappings back together based on the values. Is there an easier way to do this though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `union all` and some "fill in logic"

```
select foo_id, identifier_type, value, start_date, end_date
from t
union all
-- add the first record
select foo_id, identifier_type, NULL, '1990-01-01',
       start_date - interval 1 day
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by foo_id, identifier_type order by start_date) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1 and start_date > '1990-01-01'
union all
-- add the rest
select foo_id, identifier_type, null, end_date,
       coalesce(next_start_date - interval 1 day, '2100-12-31')
from (select t.*,
             lead(start_date) over (partition by foo_id, identifier_type order by start_date) as next_start_date
      from t
     ) t
where next_start_date <> end_date + interval 1 day and
      end_date <> '2100-12-31';
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=411a4758504a67b5a0e4b3c72e88d4cb) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Getting my first ever @Gordon Linoff answer has made my day.